# SQL Server 2005 Express: In Database Properties Transaction log filegroup currently says 'Not Applicable'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

The database files (mdf ldf) were taken from a crashed machine and loaded using the attach method. Since everything has been working fine, except when i try to truncate the transaction log the file size does not change and i now notice that it says Not Applicable against the filegroup entry for the transaction log in database properties.

Is the transaction log not active? Did i not attach it correctly? How can i check?

EDIT: There is no option to backup the transaction log in the Backup Window of management studio express either

Comment: And this is a database and definitely not a database snapshot?

Comment: absolutely, the database mdf file is in the PRIMARY filegroup, which the ldf file is NOT APPLICABLE. I wander if i did not attach the log properly? I havent noticed any decreased functionality though

Answer (score 3):

This is standard behaviour - log files are not part of any filegroup - I've just checked a couple of my databases to confirm this (I wasn't sure one way or another but I am now) - so nothing to fear.

Regarding not being able to truncate the log file, which recovery model are you using?

Comment: there is no option to backup the transaction log in the management studio backup window

Comment: Have you performed a full backup of the database since restoring it onto the server?

Comment: yep, backup just before trying to truncate

Comment: And you can insert / update against the database?  (A check that the transaction log is intact, which I'm sure it is anyway).

Comment: Does this work?

USE <yourdatabasename>
GO
BACKUP LOG <yourdatabasename> WITH TRUNCATE_ONLY

Comment: BTW - truncating the log will not change the file size - it'll merely free up space within the log file for future transactions.

Comment: Just checked and the recovery model is actually set to simple.